pandas dataframe - what is the name of the default index column?
How do I reference the default index column in a pandas dataframe?
df.set_index(['index', 'second_column'])


NOT using reset_index()

or if i wanted to rename the default index column
df.rename(columns={'index': 'new_column_name'})


The index isn't a column, it's an index. And by default, its name is None, which is not displayed. In other words, it doesn't have a name.

To reference the default index you can use:
df.index

To rename the index you can use:
df.index.name = 'new_name'


Also df = df.set_index('my_col') would change to using an existing column my_col as an index.
